# Is it possible to run the countup timer app to run in background on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

The question is self-explanatory.I have designed a counter app to run in background but I can't seem to find a way to run it in background.

I created a background worker then add the following code to it runworkerasync method:

```
void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
                timer.Start();
            });
        }
```

And this code just gets paused whenever I navigate away from the app.Any ideas to make it work?

Comment: What are you counting, just the elapsed time?

Comment: No,actually I am(was...arrgh) designing just another audio recording app which can run in background but turns out that WP devices does not support audio recording in background.

Comment: Well yeah, looks like a dead end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "No" . App tombstones or deactivates as soon it is moved to the bac